# How do I open a .dmg file from my code?

Tags: cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I am writing a cocoa app using Xamarin.Mac.
I have downloaded a file into the downloads folder. Now I want to open the file that I downloaded. How do I do that ?
FileStream Open (String path, FileMode mode)does not work.

Comment: I think you have to ask the OS to mount it, then you can access it's contents

Answer (score 1):

The `DiskImages.framework` is private, so everyone just uses the OS provided `hdiutl` to mount, unmount, verify, etc... `.dmg`'s.

### Mount a `.dmg`:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("/usr/bin/hdiutil", "attach /monodevelop/main/build/MacOSX/MonoDevelop-6.1.0.767.dmg");
```

### Unmount the file system (`.dmg` provided):

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("/usr/bin/hdiutil", "detach /Volumes/MonoDevelop");
```

### Detailed Mount Info:

If you need detailed information concerning the `.dmg` that you are mounting, you can request plist-style output and can capture that on your `Process` stdout for XML parsing:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("/usr/bin/hdiutil", "attach -plist /monodevelop/main/build/MacOSX/MonoDevelop-6.1.0.767.dmg");
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>system-entities</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>content-hint</key>
            <string>Apple_HFS</string>
            <key>dev-entry</key>
            <string>/dev/disk2s1</string>
            <key>mount-point</key>
            <string>/Volumes/MonoDevelop</string>
            <key>potentially-mountable</key>
            <true/>
            <key>unmapped-content-hint</key>
            <string>48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC</string>
            <key>volume-kind</key>
            <string>hfs</string>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>content-hint</key>
            <string>GUID_partition_scheme</string>
            <key>dev-entry</key>
            <string>/dev/disk2</string>
            <key>potentially-mountable</key>
            <false/>
            <key>unmapped-content-hint</key>
            <string>GUID_partition_scheme</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Hi, I'm just having to dig into hdiutil private framworks in order to attach DMG file programmatically (file that represent disk image with since HFS+ partition). I wonder if you happen to dig a little inside `DiskImages` framework and look for the right method ? thanks

Comment: @Zohar81 I just wrap `hdiutil` in `NSTask` processes to execute the various command's verbs since if `hdiutil` can not process your `dmg` then the private api will not be able to either. FYI: There has never been any header(s) files published for `DiskImages` that I know of and all the 3rd party Cocoa libraries that I have seen do the same thing (either via NSTasks or AppleScript)